# Grid view with background image horizontal scrolling

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to implement a grid view menu, with horizontal background scroll of three images triggered by swipe gesture, so only the background images are scrolled while icons remain still. I investigated AQGridView, GMGridView, OHGridView, but they seem to not include this feature, so I decided to  implement my own grid view with custom buttons placed in grid formation. My doubts are how to implement the background image scroll. I have searched for different solutions, but I'm not able to figure out how to solve it.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you could make a view with 2 subviews: a) the grid of icons (`UIImageView`) and b) a scroll view with your background images in paging mode (`UIScrollViewController`).

Just make sure your icons do not receive touches, so that the scrollview gets the touches.

If you want to make the icons tap-able, then it's a little more complicated; you could create an invisible layer on top and then manually handle the touches, which will get complicated. Or, what I would do, place the icons as subviews on the plain scrollview, and then move the icons in the equal and opposite direction that the scrollview is moving in to create the illusion that the icons are standing still, this will simplest to implement but is a bit of a hack. Mathematically speaking you want to apply a transformation to the scrollview and apply the opposite transformation to the icons which are in the scrollview's coordinate system so that in the global coordinate system (the screen) your icons do not move.

Comment: many thanks for your indications. Yes, my icons are tap-able.